# CSS Scopes Equation without Combine

Tags: css, less, stylesheet

I need to `equation` without `combine` multiple scopes, for example with native:

#### Native CSS:

```
.test 
{
    color: black;
}

.demo 
{
    color: black;
}
```

#### And combined version:

```
.test,
.demo 
{
    color: black;
}
```

#### But i need following:

```
@.test: .demo; // Something like that equation, all test classes equal demo class

.demo 
{
    color: black;
}
```

If it isnt possible with `CSS`, **as a last resort** i can use `LESS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LESS, You can use the `extend` function to achieve this.

```
.demo 
{
    color: black;
}
.test:extend(.demo){}; /* extends the properties of the .demo */
/* .test:extend(.demo all){}; /* the all keyword would extend nested sub classes of .demo also */
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/chvyk)

Comment: Great, that's i need! But isnt it possible with native CSS?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible with pure CSS unless writing specifically like in your combined version sample.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Harrys answer, you can do this with SASS like this:

```
.demo 
{
    color: black;
}
.test {
  @extend .demo;
}
```

[[ SAMPLE ]](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iorni)